# Removing specific ticks from matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to remove the origin ticks from my plot below to stop them overlapping, alternatively just moving them away from each other would also be great I tried this:

[image]

```
xticks = ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()
xticks[0].label1.set_visible(False)
yticks = ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()
yticks[0].label1.set_visible(False)
```

However this removed the first and last ticks from the y axis like so:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea about how to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Added more example code

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.xlabel(xlab)
plt.ylabel(ylab)
ax.spines["right"].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.spines["bottom"].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
ax.spines['left'].set_color('black')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('black')
ax.tick_params(colors='black')
xticks = ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()
xticks[0].label1.set_visible(False)
yticks = ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()
yticks[-1].label1.set_visible(False)
for x, y in all:
    ax.plot(x, y, 'ro')
```

Answer (score 11):

You were almost there. The origin of the y axis is at the bottom. This means that the tick that you want to delete, being at the top, is the last one, that is `yticks[-1]`:

```
yticks[-1].set_visible(False)
```

Comment: so close yet so far, I tried both answers here and they had different results! Setting yticks to [-1] that removed the label at -145, what I don't understand is how my original effort managed to remove 2 ticks from the y axis

Comment: but it is not a minimal WORKING example.

Comment: Sorry what else do you need for it?

Comment: the script should reproduce the error you describe. If i try to run your snippet I'd clearly get errors, since for example `all` is not defined.

Comment: all is a list of data passed to this function I don't think you want the data as well do you?

Comment: no, I want a script that reproduces the error you describe. This is a common request here at SO

Comment: Isn't yticks a function? [matplotlib.pyplot.yticks] How can you apply an index to it?

Answer (score 9):

Why not simply doing

```py
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[1:])
ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks()[:-1])
```

with `ax` being the axis object.

Comment: in matplotlib 3.0.2 this hides all tick labels. WTH?

Answer (score 2):

```
ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()[0].draw = lambda *args:None
ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()[-1].draw = lambda *args:None
```

Comment: I tried both answers and this managed to remove the label at 0.2 but then the tick at -145 instead of 140