# Recreating decision-boundary plot in python with scikit-learn and matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scikit-learn, knn

I found this wonderful graph in post here [Variation on "How to plot decision boundary of a k-nearest neighbor classifier from Elements of Statistical Learning?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234621/variation-on-how-to-plot-decision-boundary-of-a-k-nearest-neighbor-classifier-f). In this example K-NN is used to clasify data into three classes. I especially enjoy that it features the probability of class membership as a indication of the "confidence".

[image]

`r` and `ggplot` seem to do a great job.I wonder, whether this can be re-created in python? My initial thought tends to `scikit-learn` and `matplotlib`. Here is the iris example from scikit:

```
print(__doc__)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from sklearn import neighbors, datasets

n_neighbors = 15

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features. We could
                      # avoid this ugly slicing by using a two-dim dataset
y = iris.target

h = .02  # step size in the mesh

# Create color maps
cmap_light = ListedColormap(['#FFAAAA', '#AAFFAA', '#AAAAFF'])
cmap_bold = ListedColormap(['#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF'])

for weights in ['uniform', 'distance']:
    # we create an instance of Neighbours Classifier and fit the data.
    clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors, weights=weights)
    clf.fit(X, y)

    # Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
    # point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].
    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

    # Put the result into a color plot
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    plt.figure()
    plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_light)

    # Plot also the training points
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=cmap_bold)
    plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
    plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
    plt.title("3-Class classification (k = %i, weights = '%s')"
              % (n_neighbors, weights))

plt.show()
```

This produces a graph in a sense very similar:

[image]

I have three questions:

- How can I introduce the confidence to the plot?
- How can I plot the decision-boundaries with a connected line?
- Let's say I have a new observation, how can I introduce it to the plot and plot if it is classified correctly?

Comment: for the confidence intervals take a look at the library `seaborn` and its function `regplot`. http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html

Comment: As far as I understand, seaborn estimates CIs. Yet, in this case, they should result from k-NN. Would that be possible?

Comment: Are the confidences in `clf` or where would you get them from?

Comment: That is my implicit question. In order to calculate decision boundaries, `clf` needs confidences - so there should be there somewhere. But I can't find it in the documentation anywhere...

Answer (score 11):

I stumbled upon your question about a year ago, and loved the plot -- I just never got around to answering it, until now. Hopefully the code comments below are self-explanitory enough (I also [blogged](https://www.tvhahn.com/posts/beautiful-plots-decision-boundary/) about, if you want more details). Maybe four years too late, haha.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
from sklearn import neighbors

iris = datasets.load_iris()
x = iris.data[:,0:2] 
y = iris.target

# create the x0, x1 feature
x0 = x[:,0]
x1 = x[:,1]

# set main parameters for KNN plot
N_NEIGHBORS = 15 # KNN number of neighbors
H = 0.1 # mesh stepsize
PROB_DOT_SCALE = 40 # modifier to scale the probability dots
PROB_DOT_SCALE_POWER = 3 # exponential used to increase/decrease size of prob dots
TRUE_DOT_SIZE = 50 # size of the true labels
PAD = 1.0 # how much to "pad" around the true labels

clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(N_NEIGHBORS, weights='uniform')
clf.fit(x, y)

# find the min/max points for both x0 and x1 features
# these min/max values will be used to set the bounds
# for the plot
x0_min, x0_max = np.round(x0.min())-PAD, np.round(x0.max()+PAD)
x1_min, x1_max = np.round(x1.min())-PAD, np.round(x1.max()+PAD)

# create 1D arrays representing the range of probability data points
# on both the x0 and x1 axes.
x0_axis_range = np.arange(x0_min,x0_max, H)
x1_axis_range = np.arange(x1_min,x1_max, H)

# create meshgrid between the two axis ranges
xx0, xx1 = np.meshgrid(x0_axis_range, x1_axis_range)

# put the xx in the same dimensional format as the original x
# because it's easier to work with that way (at least for me)
# * shape will be: [no_dots, no_dimensions]
#   where no_dimensions = 2 (x0 and x1 axis)
xx = np.reshape(np.stack((xx0.ravel(),xx1.ravel()),axis=1),(-1,2))

yy_hat = clf.predict(xx) # prediction of all the little dots
yy_prob = clf.predict_proba(xx) # probability of each dot being 
                                # the predicted color
yy_size = np.max(yy_prob, axis=1)

# make figure
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid') # set style because it looks nice
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(8,6), dpi=150)

# establish colors and colormap
#  * color blind colors, from 
#  https://towardsdatascience.com/two-simple-steps-to-create-colorblind-friendly-data-visualizations-2ed781a167ec
redish = '#d73027'
orangeish = '#fc8d59'
yellowish = '#fee090'
blueish = '#4575b4'
colormap = np.array([redish,blueish,orangeish])

# plot all the little dots, position defined by the xx values, color
# defined by the knn predictions (yy_hat), and size defined by the 
# probability of that color (yy_prob)
# * because the yy_hat values are either 0, 1, 2, we can use 
#   these as values to index into the colormap array
# * size of dots (the probability) increases exponentially (^3), so that there is
#   a nice difference between different probabilities. I'm sure there is a more
#   elegant way to do this though...
# * linewidths=0 so that there are no "edges" around the dots
ax.scatter(xx[:,0], xx[:,1], c=colormap[yy_hat], alpha=0.4, 
           s=PROB_DOT_SCALE*yy_size**PROB_DOT_SCALE_POWER, linewidths=0,)

# plot the contours
# * we have to reshape the yy_hat to get it into a 
#   2D dimensional format, representing both the x0
#   and x1 axis
# * the number of levels and color scheme was manually tuned
#   to make sense for this data. Would probably change, for 
#   instance, if there were 4, or 5 (etc.) classes
ax.contour(x0_axis_range, x1_axis_range, 
           np.reshape(yy_hat,(xx0.shape[0],-1)), 
           levels=3, linewidths=1, 
           colors=[redish,blueish, blueish,orangeish,])

# plot the original x values.
# * zorder is 3 so that the dots appear above all the other dots 
ax.scatter(x[:,0], x[:,1], c=colormap[y], s=TRUE_DOT_SIZE, zorder=3, 
           linewidths=0.7, edgecolor='k')

# create legends
x_min, x_max = ax.get_xlim()
y_min, y_max = ax.get_ylim()

# set x-y labels
ax.set_ylabel(r"$x_1$")
ax.set_xlabel(r"$x_0$")

# create class legend
# Line2D properties: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html
# about size of scatter plot points: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47403507/9214620
legend_class = []
for flower_class, color in zip(['c', 's', 'v'], [blueish, redish, orangeish]):
    legend_class.append(Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', label=flower_class,ls='None',
                               markerfacecolor=color, markersize=np.sqrt(TRUE_DOT_SIZE), 
                               markeredgecolor='k', markeredgewidth=0.7))

# iterate over each of the probabilities to create prob legend
prob_values = [0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0]
legend_prob = []
for prob in prob_values:
    legend_prob.append(Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', label=prob, ls='None', alpha=0.8,
                              markerfacecolor='grey', 
                              markersize=np.sqrt(PROB_DOT_SCALE*prob**PROB_DOT_SCALE_POWER), 
                              markeredgecolor='k', markeredgewidth=0))



legend1 = ax.legend(handles=legend_class, loc='center', 
                    bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0.35),
                    frameon=False, title='class')

legend2 = ax.legend(handles=legend_prob, loc='center', 
                    bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0.65),
                    frameon=False, title='prob', )

ax.add_artist(legend1) # add legend back after it disappears

ax.set_yticks(np.arange(x1_min,x1_max, 1)) # I don't like the decimals
ax.grid(False) # remove gridlines (inherited from 'seaborn-whitegrid' style)

# only use integers for axis tick labels
# from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34880501/9214620
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))

# set the aspect ratio to 1, for looks
ax.set_aspect(1)

# remove first ticks from axis labels, for looks
# from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19503828/9214620
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[1:-1])
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(x1_min,x1_max, 1)[1:])

plt.show()
```

[image: Here's a picture of the plot (guess I need more reputation points to post...)]